# Why does a pseudo ::before triangle disappear with overflow-y is set to scroll?

Tags: css, sass

I have a pseudo element (triangle) attached to a custom dropdown. When I set the overflow-y to scroll, the triangle disappears. When I comment out that overflow-y property, the triangle returns.

I'm unaware of what I need to do to get the triangle back.

I know this is a lot of code to put into a snippet, so here's a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/dyvLNMr)**.

The area of focus is these two classes:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__options {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #005fec;
    max-height: 320px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .custom__options#storyFilter {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

**and this one...**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__options:before, 
  .custom__options:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 11px;
    top: -18px;
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #005fec;
  }
}
```

**When the `overflow-y: scroll;` is active:**

[image]

**When the `overflow-y: scroll;` is commented out:**

[image]

Comment: It doesn't disappear for me (and shouldn't, according to your code). It could be a browser quirk -- which browser are you using? Other possibilities include incorrect caching -- try clearing your cache with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge - You see it when `overflow-y: scroll;` is commented out. When the property is not commented out, then it doesn't display. I updated the OP with screenshots that support what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, `::before` creates a pseudo-element that is the `first child` of the selected element.

When you scroll, it is scrolled too. It is also a problem that you use both `::after` and `::before` for the triangle. You need only one of them.

Why it is not visible when you have not scrolled?  Read this

https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3409-using-position-absolute-inside-a-scrolling-overflow-container.htm

---

To fix, use them on an element that is fixed.`custom__select` is so.

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom__select.open:before, .custom__select.open:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 11px;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #005fec;
  }
}
```

You do not need to use both `::after` and `::before`. This does the work.

```
  .custom__select.open:before  {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 11px;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid #005fec;
  }
```